Overriding spring boot Tomcat-embeb-core Version By Adding It Explicitly
I am using spring-boot-version 2.7.18 in my maven project which provides tomcat-embed-core version 9.0.83 .I need to use tomcat version 9.0.86 .Can I exclude embed-core version from boot and add tomcat-embed-core version explicitly ? And what will be the difference at architecture level if it does work?
I tried to add tomcat-embed explicitly, my application is getting up and running but I want to know the impact it may cause by overriding tomcat version provides by spring-boot

Since you are using maven as your build tool, update properties section in your pom.xml file to add tomcat.version tag with desired version. This will override the existing version. You may validate with dependency tree after upgrade. Below is the code.
<properties>
  <tomcat.version>9.0.86</tomcat.version>
</properties>

